# print alert box in response to a ajax call in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have this jquery code in my view file

```
$('#ticket-ticket_impact_id').change(function() {

  var priority = $('#ticket-ticket_priority_id :selected').val();
  var impact = $('#ticket-ticket_impact_id :selected').val();
  if ($('#ticket-ticket_priority_id').val() == '' || $('#ticket-ticket_impact_id').val() == '') {

  } else {
    $.post('index.php?r=support/ticket/ajax-ticket-sla&ticket_priority_id=' + priority + '&ticket_impact_id=' + impact);
  }
})

$('#ticket-ticket_priority_id').change(function() {

  var priority = $('#ticket-ticket_priority_id :selected').val();
  var impact = $('#ticket-ticket_impact_id :selected').val();
  if ($('#ticket-ticket_priority_id').val() == '' || $('#ticket-ticket_impact_id').val() == '') {

  } else {
    $.post('index.php?r=support/ticket/ajax-ticket-sla&ticket_priority_id=' + priority + '&ticket_impact_id=' + impact);
  }
})
```

from here the value the of priority and impact id is sent to the controller/ajax function

```
public function actionAjaxTicketSla(){
    $ticket_priority_id=$_REQUEST['ticket_priority_id'];
    //var_dump($ticket_priority_id);die();
    $ticket_impact_id=$_REQUEST['ticket_impact_id'];
    if(Sla::find()->where(['ticket_priority_id'=>$ticket_priority_id,'ticket_impact_id'=>$ticket_impact_id])->exists())
    { 

    } else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("No sla defined!");</script>';
    }
}
```

I am not able to even echo something in response here don't know whats wrong here any help would be appreciated.

response
[image]

Comment: See the console for what you are getting as a response.

Comment: @YashParekh <script type="text/javascript">alert("hello!");</script> in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing  POST , GET and REQUEST

in ajax you use a POST but don't send nothins as POST param 
instead you pass param in url as GET params
and in action you look for REQUEST but not for GET (or post)

And you access directly to the $_REQUEST instead of using yii2 method for this

You should rethink you code  ..

anyway just as a first step 
looking to your ajax call you could  use the param you pass as get param

```
  public function actionAjaxTicketSla(){
      $request = Yii::$app->request;
      $get = $request->get();
      $ticket_priority_id=$get['ticket_priority_id'];
      //var_dump($ticket_priority_id);die();
      $ticket_impact_id=$get['ticket_impact_id'];
      if(Sla::find()->where(['ticket_priority_id'=>$ticket_priority_id,'ticket_impact_id'=>$ticket_impact_id])->exists())
      { 
          echo 'OK';
      } else{
          echo 'No sla defined';
      }
  }
```

and in client post

```
   $.post('index.php?r=support/ticket/ajax-ticket-sla&ticket_priority_id=' + 
              priority + '&ticket_impact_id=' + impact, 
                  function(data){ 
                          if (data !='OK') {
                           alert(data);
                          }
                  });
```

Comment: I saw that typo error in the first go but the error is still the same

Comment: answer update .. missing $request = Yii::$app->request;

Comment: you can do as you prefer ..  your problem for me is not the shape or the style for alert box .. but the correct logic of all component .. in ajax interaction client and server side ..

Comment: incase sla is defined I would prefer not to show any alert box? How can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try Echo in the If condition also and share the "response" (of page) from Network console.

Comment: added response screenshot

Comment: I am not sure about this but it seems you didn't handle the success response As you are getting  the response back 

$.post('index.php?r=support/ticket/ajax-ticket-sla&ticket_priority_id=' + priority + '&ticket_impact_id=' + impact);
  }
and like from jQuery Document where is the function to handle response 
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });

Answer (score 0):

Sending javascript code from the PHP server to js isn't a good practice. What you are doing is essentially making a call to the server and sending it the data and not doing anything with the resposne you've received.

Try to create a proper callback function like shown in this example,

Add a callback function (AJAX is Asynchronous, so your return is being hit before there is any data to return):

```
function returnData(param) {
  console.log(param);
}
```

Now add that callback function as a parameter to your AJAX function, and lets run it:

```
function getCartProduct(id, callback){
  $.post('sever.php', 
    function(data){
        callback(data);
    });
}

getCartProduct(id, returnData);
```

Also the server's response is treated as a string in javascript. To evaluate it as a javascript syntax, pass the string into the eval() method.

```
eval('alert("this works");');
```

Comment: still figuring it out